# Not getting response from controller in spring boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, api, rest, spring-mvc

I am learning spring boot. I am try to get response from controller by hitting http://localhost:8080 url. But unfortunate I am not get the expected response.

Here is my controller...

```
package com.learning.helloworld;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class ProductController {
    @GetMapping
    public String product(){
        System.out.println("Hi");
        return "the product is sold";
    }
}
```

Here is the pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.3</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.learning</groupId>
<artifactId>helloworld</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>helloworld</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>19</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

After hitting the http://localhost:8080 url the Browser show
[image: [![enter image description here][1]][1] [1]:]

How to solve this problem?

Comment: You have to specify the name of the war in the utl try: `http://localhost:8080/helloworld-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT`

Answer (score 1):

try defining the path that could help identify Dispatcherservlet which method to invoke.

For example, http://localhost:8080/home should resolve to below

```
@GetMapping(value = "/home")  
    public String product(){ }
```